# Using spring properties to configure SQL queries in JDBI declarative API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbi, spring-properties

I'd like to be able to configure my database table/column names from spring properties. I am using JDBI through the declarative API for data access. A sample of my code currently look like this:

```
import something.model.User;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.Bind;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlQuery;

public interface UserDAO {
    String TABLE_NAME = "user";
    String ID = "ud";
    String EMAIL = "email";
    String PASSWORD = "password";
    String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    String TYPE = "userType";

    @SqlQuery("SELECT " + ID + ", " + EMAIL + ", " + PASSWORD + ", " + FIRST_NAME + ", " + LAST_NAME + ", " + TYPE + " " +
              "FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " " +
              "WHERE " + ID + " = :" + ID
    )
    User findUserById(@Bind(ID) int id);
}
```

I'd like to use properties instead of the constants defined here, something along the lines of `String TABLE_NAME = "${myConfig.table.user.name}";`. However I was unable to find anything online on whether this can actually be done. I have a hunch that it is impossible, but just to be sure I decided to ask, maybe someone knows more on this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I only have a second so I can't provide a complete answer: in v2, you can configure a StatementRewriter that can take a SQL template and render it into the final String that will be sent to JDBC. You could wrap the default statement rewriter in one that renders the template with e.g. FreeMarker.

Comment: If you were using v3, you would do this by configuring a FreeMarker-based TemplateEngine.